# How to switch keyboard input language through ssh terminal on the remote machine? (Alt-Shift analog for ssh)

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, ssh, language-support

I'm looking for a way to change the language I give as input to the remote machine in an ssh session. All I want is an analog of the Alt+Shift shortcut, but for the remote machine. Specifically, the language I want to use is Greek. I don't want permanent change, I just want to be able to change it repeatedly whenever I want. I've installed the locale packages for Greek (`el-...`) but it seems changing the language of the local keyboard does not help with the remote machine's language. E.g. I switch to Greek on the local computer, and I write - `touch [greek characters' filename]` in the command line, but then the file appears as `???`, so there's something wrong. I don't know if it makes any difference, but I connect to the remote (Ubuntu) machine through *PuTTY in Windows* OS, and that's where I mainly intend to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this should work without a hitch - change the local input language, then the remote machine should receive the characters which a local machine would receive. It looks like the problem here is one of *encoding* or characters missing in the *font*; the file name, either when typed or when printed with `ls` or other commands, is displayed in an encoding/font which doesn't support the characters you've entered (hence the question marks). Check the encoding settings in PuTTY and verify that it's set to something compatible with Greek (UTF-8 should work).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Can you suggest a way to fix that?

Comment: oh just show the edit.tnx!